# SQL how I handle the index or do I need an index for this?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table product.

```
id | name | info | provider_id
```

Anyone can create a product and provider_id is for the person who connect their product from his shopify store so provider_id can be null he can also create a normal product.

So if I recieve a shopify webhook then I get the product id which I store in provider_id.

Now I make a select statement where I say

```
SELECT name, info, ..... FROM product WHERE provider_id = ...
```

I use this statement only when I recieve webhooks, so now should I use an index ? But when yes it can be null so if I dont use an index it scans all rows what can I do now ?

Comment: You should start running the query as is to see if it's slow (a lot of rows).  If it's slow and provider_id is selective (contains many unique values across rows) then creating an index should speed it up.  `provider_id = ...` will only select non-null values.  If you want null values the syntax is `provider_id is null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create **filtered index** on provider_id only for 'webhooks' in name field like below

**create index provider_id_webhook on product(provider_id) where name='webhooks';**

Comment: But I have to use where provider_id=unique Number

Comment: if the expected cardinality or number distinct values for provider_id is limited index won't help. So if the product can get from multiple provider then an index maybe helpful but if it from same provider you don't really need an index.